Kafka Consumer Failing Offset Commit After Processing - Frequent Rebalance Issue
Question:
I'm working with a Kafka consumer configured as follows:

mx_max_poll_interval: 3600000 ms (1 hour)
mx_max_poll_records: 500
mx_max_poll_records_dataset: 500
mx_recon_max_concurrency: 8
mx_recon_max_concurrency_dataset: 8
mx_session_timeout_ms: 60000 ms (1 minute)

The consumer batch takes around 2 minutes to process approximately, and I’m seeing the following logs during rebalancing:
So the consumer thread starts at 22:52:56.847 and it ends 22:52:56.896
Before this logger : "Successfully processed and acknowledged unit sync data messages"  have acknowledge
``java
ack.acknowledge();
log.info("Successfully processed and acknowledged unit sync data messages.");  // Log successful acknowledgment

```plaintext
22:52:56.896 [Consumer clientId=consumer-recon-data-set-unit-sync-data-60, groupId=recon-data-set-unit-sync-data] Failing OffsetCommit request since the consumer is not part of an active group
22:52:56.896 Successfully processed and acknowledged unit sync data messages.
22:52:56.962 [Consumer clientId=consumer-recon-data-set-unit-sync-data-60, groupId=recon-data-set-unit-sync-data] Failing OffsetCommit request since the consumer is not part of an active group
22:52:56.964 [Consumer clientId=consumer-recon-data-set-unit-sync-data-60, groupId=recon-data-set-unit-sync-data] Rebalance failed.
22:52:56.964 [Consumer clientId=consumer-recon-data-set-unit-sync-data-60, groupId=recon-data-set-unit-sync-data] (Re-)joining group

It seems that even after successfully processing and acknowledging the batch, the consumer is not able to commit offsets due to not being part of an active group. This results in the batch being reprocessed after the rebalance. Here’s what I’ve tried and observed:

Extended mx_max_poll_interval to 1 hour to ensure processing time is covered.
mx_session_timeout_ms is set to 60000 ms - could this be causing the consumer to drop from the group due to heartbeat timeout?
Checked for frequent consumer group membership changes, but nothing unusual seems to be happening in terms of scaling.

Questions:

Could the mx_session_timeout_ms setting be causing these rebalances, and if so, should I increase it to 90000 or 120000 ms?
Are there other potential configurations or resource factors (e.g., broker load or network stability) that could be causing the consumer to lose group membership?
How can I ensure that my batch processing won’t lead to reprocessing, and what adjustments might help stabilize the consumer group?

Any insights on troubleshooting these offset commit failures and rebalancing issues would be greatly appreciated!
